# Axios connection inside of computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access my mysql db inside of computed. I need to wait for my **orderList** variable to get updated. Well i kinda make things work but the thing is it should only update my **orderList** when my **filter** variable changed. Instead it updates it one after another. Here is the code:

```
computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {

       if (this.filter === '') {
            return this.orderList
        }

        let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            axios.get('/api/admin/order/filter/' + this.filter)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.error !== undefined) {
                        this.curView = 'error'
                        this.error = response.data.error
                        return
                    }
                    this.curView = 'pageOrderlist'
                    response.data.data.forEach(e => { e.cur = 'loading' })
                    resolve(response.data.data); // Yay! Everything went well!
                })
        });

        myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
            this.orderList = successMessage
        });

        return this.orderList 
    }
```

[calls it after and after again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H3Jt.png)
What am i missing? Can you guys help me out please?

Comment: computed is not the best place to do this, use created to fetch the data, use it as a reactive property then later whenever that value changes your computed gets re-calculated

Comment: _" I need to wait for my orderList variable to get updated"_ - [use a watcher](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) and there perform the necessary logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **watch** on `filter` variable and if it is empty then execute the `axios` from methods.

Meaning, it will watch the filter variable whether it is empty or not, and if it finds it empty it will execute axios api request.

i think, you do not need promises, and also do not use computed.